# Graph generic equations with pgfplots in Latex

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

Using pgfplots I would like to create a 'generic graph'.  For example, I have the equation:

[image: Generic equation]

Where m and k are constants.  g is force due to gravity.

I do not wish to use specific value for m and k.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what your question is. In terms of presentation draw it as a function of alpha:=(m/k) AND parametrize t as multiples of alpha. Have a look at nomograms which were used before calculators were widely available.

Comment: "Thou shall not comment in the middle of the night ..." // You're right, I made a mistake. The unity test is fine: it's a velocity. // Deleted the comments.

Comment: Do you know what the figure would look like? Can you draw it on paper? It seems you want to plot v(t, m, k), right? You can go over different values of k and m and draw on top of each other if that's what you need.